# I can't connect my Keycloak server to my Postgres database, I keep getting password authentification failed. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, keycloak

I am trying to connect a Postgres database to my Keycloak server to persistently save realms and users. But the password authentication fails even though I know the password is correct. This is my yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgresDB
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloakdb
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak_demo_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - custom-keycloak
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloakdb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresDB:5432/keycloakdb
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak_demo_user
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks: 
      - custom-keycloak
    volumes:
      - /Users/[username]/custom-theme⁠:/opt/keycloak/themes/custom-theme
      - keycloakdata:/opt/keycloak/data/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  pgdata:
  keycloakdata:

networks:
  custom-keycloak:
    name: custom-keycloak
    driver: bridge
```

This is the error I am getting

```
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,415 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,467 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,724 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': FATAL: password authentication failed for user "keycloak_demo_user"
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,748 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,749 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,749 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "keycloak_demo_user"
2024-02-05 14:49:08 2024-02-05 13:49:08,749 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

Comment: did you found a solution for your problem?